# Finding whether a string meets a certain pattern

Tags: java, string

I recently had an interview with Google for a Software Engineering position and the question asked regarded building a pattern matcher.

So you have to build the

```
boolean isPattern(String givenPattern, String stringToMatch)
```

Function that does the following:

`givenPattern` is a string that contains:

```
a) 'a'-'z' chars
b) '*' chars which can be matched by 0 or more letters
c) '?' which just matches to a character - any letter basically
```

So the call could be something like

`isPattern("abc", "abcd")` - returns false as it does not match the pattern ('d' is extra)

`isPattern("a*bc", "aksakwjahwhajahbcdbc")`, which is true as we have an 'a' at the start, many characters after and then it ends with "bc"

`isPattern("a?bc", "adbc")` returns true as each character of the pattern matches in the given string.

During the interview, time being short, I figured one could walk through the pattern, see if a character is a letter, a * or a ? and then match the characters in the given string respectively. But that ended up being a complicated set of for-loops and we didn't manage to come to a conclusion within the given 45 minutes.

Could someone please tell me how they would solve this problem quickly and efficiently?

Many thanks!

Comment: The easiest way would be to write a method for translating this pattern syntax to Java regular expressions: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/

Comment: Classic Dynamic Programming question.

Comment: Okay. That WAS my question as well. Are you allowed to use regex? If yes, then this should be relatively easy as depicted in the code by @assylias.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
boolean isPattern(String givenPattern, String stringToMatch) {
    if (givenPattern.empty)
        return stringToMatch.isEmpty();
    char patternCh = givenPatter.charAt(0);
    boolean atEnd = stringToMatch.isEmpty();
    if (patternCh == '*') {
        return isPattenn(givenPattern.substring(1), stringToMatch)
            || (!atEnd && isPattern(givenPattern, stringToMatch.substring(1)));
    } else if (patternCh == '?') {
        return !atEnd && isPattern(givenPattern.substring(1), 
            stringToMatch.substring(1));
    }
    return !atEnd && patternCh == stringToMatch.charAt(0)
          && isPattern(givenPattern.substring(1), stringToNatch.subtring(1);
}
```

(Recursion being easiest to understand.)

Comment: I think your first return there is malformed, you are only passing one parameter to isPattern and it is a boolean. Also you are missing a semicolon.

Comment: I think you want `return !atEnd && isPattern(givenPattern, stringToMatch.substring(1));`

Comment: @JamesMcMahon perfect. Corrected it.

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you are allowed to use regexes, you could have written something like:

```
static boolean isPattern(String givenPattern, String stringToMatch) {
    String regex = "^" + givenPattern.replace("*", ".*").replace("?", ".") + "$";

    return Pattern.compile(regex).matcher(stringToMatch).matches();
}
```

`"^"` is the start of the string
`"$"` is the end of the string
`.` is for "any character", exactly once
`.*` is for "any character", 0 or more times

Note: If you want to restrict `*` and `?` to letters only, you can use `[a-zA-Z]` instead of `.`.

Comment: Mind putting some additional information around the structure of the regex itself? I think it would improve the answer.

Comment: what if the given string has regex wildcards but are not to be interpreted as such? You would have to escape all known regex wildcards before using it.

Comment: @RalfHoppen Yes you are right, it assumes the `stringToMatch` only contains letters.

Comment: Based on the input rules given by Sorin, I think that is a reasonable assumption.

Comment: You're right. It's a good solution, but I don't think they would accept it, as they're probably trying to see how you would solve this problem with only "basic functions". I had a similar question.

Comment: @RalfHoppen, knowing Google this question was probably a prelude to questions about manhole covers.